# Add links to post icon in help page is obsolete

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, privileges, help-center

In the [Remove New User Restrictions - Privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user) page under **How do I add links to my posts?** section, among one of the point it was described as, by using this icon [image: Editor Icon] in the editor toolbar you can add a link to a post.

But as per the current editor toolbar, the icon mentioned in the help page is not exists. The icon in the **help center** page need to be update.

Screen shot for reference:

> [image: Editor toolbar doesn't have that icon mentioned in the help page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that certainly took a keen eye to spot :) I've updated the help center here on MSE which (should) soon propagate to the rest of the network help centers.

Thanks!

Comment: It was fixed in the MSE `rev 2016.2.12.4155`